# Why are the variables in the respositories section not being resolved in the POM.xml?

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pom.xml, gitlab-api

I can't seem to understand why the variables in the repositories section in my POM are not being resolved. The variables in other sections are being parsed perfectly.
We use Gitlab CI/CD and the predefined variable are not being resolved in the repositories section the POM.xml
In other sections, such as dependencies, etc, they are being resolved perfectly

The asterisks in the urls and artefacts are for privacy reasons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>***.***</groupId>
<artifactId>***-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.1.1</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>maven-via-deploy-token</id>
    <url>${CI_API_V4_URL}/groups/****/-/packages/maven</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>

<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>gitlab-maven</id>
    <url>${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${env.CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
  </repository>
  
  <snapshotRepository>
    <id>gitlab-maven</id>
    <url>${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${env.CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

</project>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is because inheritence happens before interpolation of variables (see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-model-builder/). So first all parents are resolved, and that can only be done when repositories are explicit.

Another issue you might face is when the pom is deployed. In that case the value of such property might be unknown, which might give unexpected results.

Overall a repository should be handled as a constant, not a variable.